# Record audio and send the last recorded audio through email

Tags: android

I would like to record audio for 20 seconds.For that i need to launch an audio recording app from my current application and i have launched it by calling intent.I was able to record and save the audio.But I don't know how to stop recording after 20 secs and send that audio through email.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After starting recording you can fire a handler with delay of 20 sec, There you can stop the recording, and can send email. Sending email can not be done directly from app, it needs a email client, Using the below code you can attach a file and start an intent for an email client.

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(

                android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);

                emailIntent.setType("application/octet-stream");

                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[] { "" });

                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"");

                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"");

                ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
                ArrayList<String> filePaths=new ArrayList<String>();
                        String fullpath="";
                        fullpath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"yourfilename.mp3";
                        filePaths.add(fullpath);
                for (String file : filePaths)
                {
                    File fileIn = new File(file);
                    if(fileIn.exists()){
                        Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
                        uris.add(u);
                    }
                }
                emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
                YourActivity.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,"Send mail..."));
```